# Save List Item Edits After Timeout?

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, list-view, list-form, time-out

The new list item form occasionally times out while I am adding a new item to a list. When the form times out, it erases any work I did. Is there any way to save my work on the new list item when it times out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to save your work when it times out.

As a workaround, you could try to increase the default execution Timeout in web.config file.

Please refer to https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/1d816511-dc43-46ab-8e94-71f3bfa62700/sharepoint-2013-page-saving-bug-time-out-issues?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.